# How to debug ShareLock in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I am seeing quite a few occurrences of the following in my Postgres server log:

```
LOG:  process x still waiting for ShareLock on transaction y after 1000.109 ms 
DETAIL:  Process holding the lock: z. Wait queue: x.
CONTEXT:  while inserting index tuple (a,b) in relation "my_test_table"
    SQL function "my_test_function" statement 1 
...
LOG:  process x acquired ShareLock on transaction y after 1013.664 ms
CONTEXT:  while inserting index tuple (a,b) in relation "my_test_table"
```

I am running Postgres **9.5.3**. In addition I am running on Heroku so I don't have access to the fine grained superuser-only debugging tools.

I am wondering how best to debug such an issue given these constraints and the fact each individual lock is relatively transient (generally 1000-2000ms).

Things I have tried:

- Monitoring [`pg_locks`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/view-pg-locks.html) (and joining to [`pg_class`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/catalog-pg-class.html) for context).
- Investigating [`pageinspect`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/pageinspect.html).
- Replicating locally both by hand and with [`pgbench`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/pgbench.html) where I do have superuser perms. I have so far been unable to replicate the issue locally (I *suspect* due to having a much smaller data set but I can't be sure).

It is worth noting that CPU utilisation appears high (load average of >1) when I see these issues so it's possible there is nothing wrong with the above per se and that I'm seeing it as a consequence of insufficient system resources being available. I would still like to understand how best to debug it though so I can understand what exactly is happening.

Comment: Did you find a way to not get the deadlock in this case?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

The key thing is that it's a ShareLock on the *transaction*.

This means that one transaction is waiting for another to commit/rollback before it can proceed. It's only loosely a "lock". What's happening here is that a PostgreSQL transaction takes an ExclusiveLock on its own transaction ID when it starts. Other transactions that want to wait for it to finish can try to acquire a ShareLock on the transaction, which will block until the ExclusiveLock is released on commit/abort. It's basically using the locking mechanism as a convenience to implement inter-transaction completion signalling.

This usually happens when the waiting transaction(s) are trying to `INSERT` a `UNIQUE` or `PRIMARY KEY` value for a row that's recently inserted/modified by the waited-on transaction. The waiting transactions cannot proceed until they know the outcome of the waited-on transaction - whether it committed or rolled back, and if it committed, whether the target row got deleted/inserted/whatever.

That's consistent with what's in your error message. proc "x" is trying to insert into "my_test_table" and has to wait until proc "y" commits xact "z" to find out whether to raise a unique violation or whether it can proceed.

Most likely you have contention in some kind of upsert or queue processing system. This can also happen if you have some function/transaction pattern that tries to insert into a heavily contended table, then does a lot of other time consuming work before it commits.

Comment: |||| |||| |||| ||||| || <-- The "Craig Ringer saves me again" count.

Comment: @markdsievers I gotta ask, are the sets of 4 really sets of 4, or are they the 4 + strike that is normal in EN tallying? Would you use alternate tally marks if you were using unicode? Why is one of the tally's a 5 while the others are 4? Should both sides of the "<" be converted to a number? And then what is the value of a deprecated 'The "Craig Ringer saves me again" count'?

Comment: @cwallenpoole You are quite right. Comments aren't editable after a couple hours of publishing, sorry for that. Please accept the sentiment in the spirit it was given.